# jQuery: replace elements with other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

Is there a simple way to replace selected elements with other elements?

I thought `replaceWith` would do that, but it actually replaces every occurrence with provided elements. So in my case, it actually duplicates elements (because it does for every occurrence).

Consider this example:

```js
var html = '<option value="8">15% Discount</option><option value="9">18% Discount</option>'
$('.discount_select option:not(:first)').replaceWith(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="discount_select">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="4">45% Discount</option>
  <option value="5">10% Discount</option>
</select>
```

Result is that new options are duplicated. I get two `15%` and two `18%` options. But I need to just replace selected options with provided option (and not do this for every option one by one).

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/6on7mzqw/

P.S. I guess it is possible to first remove not needed elements and then append new elements, but maybe there is simpler way?

Comment: That is because your selector will catch two options and will replace them both with the full html. Try making specific selectors.

Comment: @Marnix I know that, I explained in question. How can I make it more specific?

Comment: As you have the new source in a single html string format, removing the obsolete options and putting in the new ones in one go is the way. Do you have the option to change the data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the new content from the HTML before the first one selected, then go back to the original selection and remove them.

```js
var html = '<option value="8">15% Discount</option><option value="9">18% Discount</option>'
$('.discount_select option:not(:first)')
.first().before(html).end().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="discount_select">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="4">45% Discount</option>
  <option value="5">10% Discount</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no method in jQuery that handles this specific case, so we can just remove and add new elements.

```
var html = '<option value="8">15% Discount</option><option value="9">18% Discount</option>'

$('.discount_select option:not(:first)').remove();
$('.discount_select option:first').after(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can use child selector **:nth-child(n)** 
  to select specific element by order 
like this

```js
var html = '<option value="8">15% Discount</option><option value="9">18% Discount</option>'

$('.discount_select option:nth-child(2)').replaceWith(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="discount_select">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="4">45% Discount</option>
  <option value="5">10% Discount</option>
</select>
```

there are many solutions for your problem and that one of them

Comment: This does not replace elements. You left 10%.

Comment: I don't know that you want to replace the two elements Ok I will edit my answer for you

Comment: what a bout making the html variable as an array ?

Answer (score 0):

You are better of removing the unnecessary options and add the new ones in one go. The solution below makes this in one operation, meaning that is rewriting the DOM only once, which is considered a good practice in terms of speed.

```
var html = '<option value="8">15% Discount</option><option value="9">18% Discount</option>';
$('.discount_select').html(
    $('.discount_select option').first().add(html)
);
```